# What method is called when a QGraphicsItem get selected

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem

Probably a trick question, but I can't find the answer.

I need to know when a QGraphicsItem gets selected. There must be a method that's called.

I know `QGraphicsItem::itemChange()` but it's called too often.

Is there a better method ?

thx

edit : With this

```
if(change == ItemSelectedChange && scene()){
    cout << "haha " << i++ << endl;
}
```

I get two calls every selection change.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should take `value` into consideration in the QGraphicsItem::itemChange method. What you want is probably something like this:

```
QVariant YourItem::itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value)
{
    if (change == QGraphicsItem::ItemSelectedChange)
    {
        if (value == true)
        {
            // do stuff if selected
        }
        else
        {
            // do stuff if not selected
        }
    }

    return QGraphicsItem::itemChange(change, value);
}
```

Comment: Thx Works better than what I found : add && this.isSelected() in the if.

Comment: @Anthony, I have a question on the else part. When I select another graphics item, the else part is getting triggered. I understand that. I am facing an issue that i need to get the else part triggered while on mouse press on another graphics item. Now it is triggering only when i press and release the mouse button on another graphics item. Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: @GUI-Novice I would try calling scene()->clearSelection() in the other item's mousePressEvent to ensure that this item gets deselected on a mouse press.

Answer (score 0):

[`QGraphicsScene::selectionChanged`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#selectionChanged)

Comment: You'd have to iterate over all [selected items](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#selectedItems]) and manually set the ones in question [selected](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setSelected).